# Hibernate Session is closed in spring transaction after calling method second time

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

First of all I am a beginner in spring.I have created a simple Spring service that has DAO injected and transaction is managed by HibernateTransactionManager of spring, like as below.(And transaction configuration is used using annotations )

```
@Service(value="daopowered")
public class UserServiceImplDao implements UserService
    {
    @Inject
    private UserDao userDao;


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User autheticate( String userId, String password )
    {
    return userDao.findByIdAndPassword(userId, password);
    }
```

My transaction configuration is following

```
<bean id="txMgr"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txMgr" />
```

Now the problem is when I call authenticate method first time using some controller then it works fine ( does DB operations successfully) but after calling it again second time hibernate session is closed exception is coming ? Please guide me what I am doing it wrong or how to handle this scenario ? Why wont spring opens a new transaction when I call this method second time ?

Exception Trace:

```
2013-05-22T21:04:18.041+0530 DEBUG [14208212-2] lerExceptionResolver Resolving exception from handler [com.akhi.store.controller.HomeController@5d9d277e]: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Session is closed!; nested exception is org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
2013-05-22T21:04:18.044+0530 DEBUG [14208212-2] tusExceptionResolver Resolving exception from handler [com.akhi.store.controller.HomeController@5d9d277e]: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Session is closed!; nested exception is org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
2013-05-22T21:04:18.044+0530 DEBUG [14208212-2] lerExceptionResolver Resolving exception from handler [com.akhi.store.controller.HomeController@5d9d277e]: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Session is closed!; nested exception is org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
2013-05-22T21:04:18.046+0530 DEBUG [14208212-2] et.DispatcherServlet Could not complete request
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Session is closed!; nested exception is org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:658)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.convertHibernateAccessException(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:245)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:224)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.findByIdAndPassword(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT: The DAO code

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends GenericHibernateDAO<User, Long>
                                implements
                                UserDao
    {

    @Override
    public User findByIdAndPassword( String id, String password )
    {

    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.eq("userId",
                                            id)).add(Restrictions.eq("password",
                                                         password)).setMaxResults(1);
    List<?> list = crit.list();

    if (list.size() > 0)
        return (User) list.get(0);
    else
        return null;
    }
```

and getSession() implementation is

```
protected Session getSession() {
    if (session == null) {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    return session;
}
```

Also the abstract DAO class  has sessionfactory injected

```
public abstract class GenericHibernateDAO<T, ID extends Serializable>
        implements GenericDAO<T, Long> {
    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    protected Session session;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Comment: The exception is thrown when calling the DAO. Show us the DAO. Also, remove the annotation TransactionConfiguration. This annotation is used in DAO integration tests. Not in production code (where it's useless, and ignored by Spring).

Comment: Edited and included DAO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ObjectDao need a SessionFactory and the annotation Transaction. Something like this :

```
@Component
public class userDao{
       @AutoWired
       private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


       @Transactional
       public User findByIdAndPassword(String id , String password){
             ....
       }

       {getters and setters}

}
```

Dont do that :

```
protected Session getSession() {
    if (session == null) {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    return session;
}
```

just return the current session , the Transactional annotation is responsible for opening and closing sessions , like this :

```
protected Session getSession() {
    return  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

Comment: I have already done that as I said, it executes successfully first time. It breaks after calling it second time

Comment: Dont ask about the value of SessionFactory , is null or not. Just return the currentSession , @Transactional close and open sessions.

Comment: Thanks Sark, I found the solution. You are right about getSession(). I was doing it wrong way in getSession